# how to use fzf with bidirectional languages?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, fzf

I am using a bash script to provide a search utlilty to locate and open files and directories.

here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
lxterminal -e "bicon.bin locate /home /run/media |fzf >| ~/.mylocateData"
              # ^ this the problematic part
sleep 0.4
while [[ "$(pidof fzf)" != "" ]] ; do
    sleep 0.4
done
file="$(cat ~/.mylocateData)"
if [[ -z "$file" ]] ; then exit ; fi
mimetype=$(file  --dereference --brief --mime-type  "$file" )
case "$mimetype" in
      inode/directory)            lxterminal -e bicon.bin ranger "$file" ;;
      image/*)                    feh "$file" & disown ;;
      text/* | */xml)             lxterminal -e vim "$file"  ;;
      video/* | audio/*)          mpv --really-quiet --loop "$file" & disown ;;
     application/pdf)             okular "$file" & disown ;;
     application/octet-stream)
                                 if [[ "${file#*.}" == "MP3" ]]
                                    then
                                         mpv --really-quiet --loop "$file" & disown
                                 fi
                                 ;;
     *)                            lxterminal -e bicon.bin ranger --selectfile="$file" ;;
esac
```

if I run the first command with **bicon.bin** included the text of fzf handles the arabic filenames as expected, however the file name saved in **.mylocateData** file is somehow corrupted and I cannot open it. I tried some debuuging  like `ls "$(cat .mylocateData)` to confirm.

but if I run my script without **bicon.bin** fzf shows the search but with arabic characters from left to right (in an ugly way )  but the file name is correctly saved regardless and it can be opened.

**MY QUESTION** is : how can I achieve both goals ? if it is a matter of reading the file some  way other than `cat` ? or is it the use of fzf?

PS : I'm not interested in using dmenu, rofi ...etc, I love the way fzf works and I want to use it in my arch i3wm desktop